# calling a function but form id not known

Tags: jquery

Trying to call a submit function but the form id is not known. The form id will be "#viewemails_0" but the 0 could be any number.

**Here I have hard coded the form id. This works but need something more dynamic.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#viewemails_0").submit(function (e) {
        //Stops the submit request
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I have tried to do something like this but the page refreshes keeps firefox. I believe its not firing off the function properly.

**Here is what I tried but NOT working**

The window alert works and I can see the form id correctly.

```
function viewemails(obj) {
  var formname = obj.name;
  alert(formname);

  $("#"+formname).submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

  });

}
```

**Here is my HTML/PHP form**

```
<form id="viewemails_'.$i.'" name="viewemails_'.$i.'" onsubmit="return viewemails(this);">
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with PHP but don't you need to put some PHP tags for the interpreter to actually interpret that code as PHP? I bet in your rendered html the form id attribute is actually `viewemails_'.$i.'` and not viewemails_0 for example.

Comment: @Strelok no the php is working properly :) the alert shows up as viewemails_0

Comment: That's your JavaScript that's working properly. Inspect there HTML in the web browser's dev tools and see what the actual ID of the form is.

Comment: Do you have control of the PHP? if so, why not change it to make the ID unique and predicatable, like 'viewmails_main'?

Comment: @GerardSexton, it cant be predicatable as the form is generated by a php loop. Each form has to be unique. Sorry, i know you cant see it with the limited code.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to use `id` or `name` in `viewemails`. You're already passing the form element into the function. Have you tried `$(obj).submit(...)`?

Comment: someone had just posted a working answer but then he deleted it.. i didnt get to catch his name but ill post the working solution up

Comment: @user3436467 using an attribute selector does not address the problem of mixing `onsubmit` and `$('...').submit(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with explicit event callbacks (ie `onsubmit`). Use one or the other, I recommend the former.

What's happening is that when the `onsubmit` expression is executed, the form is already submitting so setting up a *submit* event listener at that point is too late. Also, seeing as you have `onsubmit="return ..."`, your `viewemails` function should be returning a boolean value.

To solely use event listeners, you can simply use a class to identify the form, ie

```
<form id="viewemails_<?= $i ?>" class="whatever"...
```

(note, no `onsubmit` is required) and in your JS

```
jQuery(function($) { // document ready handler
    $('form.whatever').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formId = this.id;
        // and so on
    });
});
```

or if you want to use event delegation (in case the form is added after the page is loaded or you don't want to use a document *ready* handler)

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', 'form.whatever', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formId = this.id;
    // etc
});
```

Comment: this is awesome. didnt know it can be done with a class. still testing but will come back to you shortly.

Comment: you said onsubmit is not required but how come? i am using that to call a separate function which will post data via ajax.

Comment: Because the submit event is being handled by the `function(e) { ... }` being used in the `.on('submit', ...)` call. You do your AJAX posting and other work where it says `// and so on` / `// etc`

Comment: since your solution dynamically sets the formname as a variable i was able to merge everything into your proposed function and it works. I was able to get rid of the onsubmit. love this solution - thank you!